# how to update an DataGridView changes with an Table Adapter C# SQL?

Tags: c#, sql

```
   public void DoUpdate()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(string connection);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table",con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        this.dataGridView1.Update();
        this.dataGridView1.Refresh();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

i use this method after an change was made in my Stock_table but the datagrid still show the old data with no changes, i only see the changes made in the table after reset my program

Comment: Please read the `Refresh` method documentation. It is constantly called in unnecessarily. In this case, it is useless. Remove it. Same with `Update` method.

Comment: As I understand it, you want to save the changes made by the user back to the DB. Then call `adapter.Update(dt)`. Of course, the `UpdateCommand` property must be set correctly.

Comment: i didnt know about UpdateCommand so i should use like  this.dataGridView1.DataSource = adapter.UpdateCommand() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   public void DoUpdate()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(string connection);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table",con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        con.Close();
    }
}
The right way to update an datagridview 
why is this a method because if you are using another form to make the data insert in your table you only need to make a constructor with the previous form and after the insert you only call this method
Thanks for the help
```